# Javascript - masking account number within a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, security

I have a fun challenge I couldn't find an answer for here. I have a string of text, that *could* potentially contain an account number.
Example:

```
"Hi, my account number is 1234 5678 9012 2345 and I'm great."
```

The account number can come in many flavours, as it's entered by the user:

Basic and potential possibilities below:

```
1234 1234 1234 1234
1234 1234 1234 1234 1
BE12 1234 1234 1234

1234-1234-1234-1234
1234.1234.1234.1234
1234123412341234
12341234 1234 1234

1234-1234-1234-1234-1
1234.1234.1234.1234.1
12341234123412341
12341 234 1234 12341

BE12-1234-1234-1234
be12-1234-1234 1234
Be12.1234.1234-1234
BE12123412341234
```

(basically integers with hyphen, space or a dot in the middle, with the exception of IBAN format, that has two characters at the beginning)

What I need as output is everything masked, except the last four digits.

```
"Hi, my account number is **** **** **** 2345 and I'm great."
```

How I think I should approach this problem:

- Analyze every string and try to find the above account no. patterns
- Create a magical regular expression that replaces the account no. they way I need
- If there's an account number, use this RegEx to do so.

What would be your approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `JavaScript` a must? Other regex engines have far better support.

Comment: I'll do this in node.js, so I guess yes. Unless there's some great npm package I don't know of.

Comment: This might be a start: [`\b[\dX][-. \dX]+(\d{4})\b`](https://regex101.com/r/RwqZzV/3/) - however more input strings are needed.

Comment: `XX123456123123` missing 2 characters and will fail any 16 number count.  `12341234123412341234` how do you have 20 numbers?

Comment: Do your account numbers follow specific rules, is there a checksum included?

Comment: EDIT: All possibilities/test scenarios added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match all of the above with:

```
\b[\dX][-. \dX]+(\d{4})\b
```

... and replace it with `*` x `strlen(match) - 4` + `\1`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/RwqZzV/3/).

---

In `JavaScript`:

```
var string = "Hi, my account number is 1234 5678 9012 2345 and I'm great.";
var new_string = string.replace(/\b[\dX][-. \dX]+(\d{4})\b/g, function(match, capture) {
    return Array(match.length-4).join("*") + capture;
});
print(new_string);
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/viDOuH).

Comment: Great! Two more items to solve here: What if the user writes other characters instead of the "XX"? Can we make it any character (upper/lowercase)? Also, the last digit of longer numbers (17 digits) was not matched :-(

Comment: @flaesh: Of course, you can make it match more, simply include the characters you want to allow in the square brackets but please provide some more realistic input strings then (edit your question, that is).

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Awesome! This helped me solve it; I just edited to: \b[\dBb][-. \dEe]+(\d{4})\b to match the "BE" instead of the "XX". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing Jan's awesome regex pattern, it can be extended to capture the last digit too (see the example below)

***Note:*** His method of using `replace()` is better, I recommend using it for clarity.  This is only to offer an alternative approach using `match()`

```js
//  Setup
let str = `1234 1234 1234 1234
1234-1234-1234-1234
12341234123412341234
1234 1234 1234 1234 1
12341234123412341
1234-1234-1234-1234-1
1234.1234.1234.1234.1
XX12 3456 1234 1234
XX123456123123
XX12-3456-1234-1234
XX12.3456.1234.1234
This is a sentence for visual proof 1234 5678 9012 3456
And some XX32 1111.2222-9999-2 more proof`,
  nums = str.split('\n');


var re = new RegExp(/(\b[\dX][-. \dX]+(\d{4}.?\d?)\b)/);

// Convert Nums
var converted = nums.map(num => {
  let match = num.match(re);

  if (match) {
    let orig = match[1],
      end    = match[2],
      hidden = orig.substr(0, orig.length - end.length);

    hidden = hidden.replace(/\S/g, "X") + end;
    num    = num.replace(orig, hidden);
  }

  return num;
});

// Visual Verification
console.log(converted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Regex with a `look ahead` trick, simply find

```
\d{4}([ -.])(?![A-Za-z])
```

and replace with

```
****\1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replace(/\b[\dX][-. \dX]+(\d{4})\b/g, '**** **** **** $1')
```

```js
console.log("Hi, my account number is 1234-5678-9012-2345 and I'm great.".replace(/\b[\dX][-. \dX]+(\d{4})\b/g, '**** **** **** $1'));
console.log("Hi, my account number is 1234 5678 9012 2345 and I'm great.".replace(/\b[\dX][-. \dX]+(\d{4})\b/g, '**** **** **** $1'));
console.log("Hi, my account number is 1234.5678.9012.2345.1 and I'm great.".replace(/\b[\dX][-. \dX]+(\d{4})\b/g, '**** **** **** $1'));
console.log("Hi, my account number is XX123456123123 and I'm great.".replace(/\b[\dX][-. \dX]+(\d{4})\b/g, '**** **** **** $1'));
```

Comment: 3rd doesn't pass

Answer (score -3):

```
const masking = function (numbers) {

  const str = String(numbers);

  //another method for converting  number to the string --const str = numbers + "";

  const slici = str.slice(-4);

  // console.log(slici);

  const padding = slici.padStart(str.length, '*');

  console.log(`Hi, my account number is ${padding} and I'm great`);

};

masking(456871398401);

masking(8235101466187);
```

Comment: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your question with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)