# Regex: Matching account numbers, but not tokens/birthdays

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling with the following regular expression:

```
\b[\dBb][-. \dEe]+(\d{4})\b
```

It should match account numbers, but not tokens/birthdays or text with "be" in it.
I have managed, with the support of the [community](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939343/7565480), to capture the first part. However, I can't seem to be able to exclude the tokens/birthdays.

Cases that should be matched (my regex works correctly):

```
1234 1234 1234 1234
1234 1234 1234 1234 1
BE12 1234 1234 1234
1234-1234-1234-1234
1234.1234.1234.1234
1234123412341234
12341234 1234 1234
1234-1234-1234-1234-1
1234.1234.1234.1234.1
12341234123412341
12341 234 1234 12341
BE12-1234-1234-1234
be12-1234-1234 1234
Be12.1234.1234-1234
BE12123412341234
```

Cases that should NOT be matched (my regex works incorrectly for some of these):

```
123456
Token: 123456
I shall be awesome in Belgium, as my birthdate is 01/01/2000.
01.01.2000
01012000
first of january 2000
```

Could you help in solving this challenge?
Thanks!

Comment: Wow, this is great! Can you submit your reply as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: Wait, if you need to match these strings in a larger text, that won't work. Also, should the valid strings end with 4 digits (as your pattern implies)?

Comment: Text will always be a string of max 256 characters with possible line breaks. The string that needs to be matched will indeed always end with 4 digits.

Comment: Sorry, if you need to extract these strings out of  a larger string, I see no way to filter out unwanted matches. The `01012000` token is similar to the first part of your expected `12341234 1234 1234` match. How can you tell one from the other?

Comment: This condition _but not tokens/birthdays or text with "be" in it_ is contradicting your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Matches BE or 2 digits, followed by 14 or 15 digits that are interspersed with spaces, periods, and dashes**

```
([Bb][Ee]|\d\d)([-. ]?\d){14,15}
```

**Test:**

```
ACCOUNT             INPUT
1234123412341234    1234 1234 1234 1234
12341234123412341   1234 1234 1234 1234 1
BE12123412341234    BE12 1234 1234 1234
1234123412341234    1234-1234-1234-1234
1234123412341234    1234.1234.1234.1234
1234123412341234    1234123412341234
1234123412341234    12341234 1234 1234
12341234123412341   1234-1234-1234-1234-1
12341234123412341   1234.1234.1234.1234.1
12341234123412341   12341234123412341
12341234123412341   12341 234 1234 12341
BE12123412341234    BE12-1234-1234-1234
be12123412341234    be12-1234-1234 1234
Be12123412341234    Be12.1234.1234-1234
BE12123412341234    BE12123412341234
No Match            123456
No Match            Token: 123456
No Match            I shall be awesome in Belgium, as my birthdate is 01/01/2000.
No Match            01.01.2000
No Match            01012000
No Match            first of january 2000
Be12123412341234    Here is my account number Be12.1234.1234-1234. have a nice day
```

**Validator (Ruby):**

```
a = [ "1234 1234 1234 1234",
...
]

puts 'ACCOUNT             INPUT'
a.each { |s|
  match = /(([Bb][Ee]|\d\d)([-. ]?\d){14,15})/ =~ s
  puts "%-18s  %s"%[ match ? $1.tr('-. ', '') : "No Match", s ]
}
```